# How to add a products to cart through Ajax in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: product-attribute

How to add a products to cart through Ajax in magento 1.9.2.4

I want a solution for this?Please anyone can help.

Comment: Add to cart product using ajax magento 1.9 GitHub so please check it.

https://github.com/manishiitg/excellence_magento_blog/tree/master/Ajax%20Add%20Cart%20Module